# I am trying to determine why I am getting a NullPointerException with my program. I need to determine what is null in my NodeLibrary class

Tags: java

I am running a java program through an application called Anylogic. I am creating a library that stores node objects for a water distribution system. I have provided the code for the two classes below. I am testing this code to see if I can access the nodes and initialize them properly. Any pointers on what is wrong with the code will help me out quite a bit.

```
/**
* NodeObject
*/  
public class NodeObject implements java.io.Serializable {

private String nodeID;
private boolean gate;
private boolean securityCamera;
private boolean isExposed;
private String nodeType;

/**
 * Default constructor
 */
public NodeObject(){
}

public void NodeObject(String nodeID, boolean gate, boolean securityCamera, boolean isExposed, String nodeType){
    this.nodeID = nodeID;
    this.gate = gate;
    this.securityCamera = securityCamera;
    this.isExposed = isExposed;
    this.nodeType = nodeType;
    return;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public void alternateConstruct(String ID, boolean gateInfo, boolean securityCameraInfo, boolean exposureInfo, String nodeTypeInfo) {
    this.nodeID = ID;
    this.gate = gateInfo;
    this.securityCamera = securityCameraInfo;
    this.isExposed = exposureInfo;
    this.nodeType = nodeTypeInfo;
    return;
}

public String getNodeID() {
    String returnval = this.nodeID;
    return returnval;
}

public boolean hasGate() {
    boolean returnval = this.gate;
    return returnval;
}

public boolean hasSecurityCamera() {
    boolean returnval = this.securityCamera;
    return returnval;
}

public boolean exposed() {
    boolean returnval = this.isExposed;
    return returnval;
}

public String getNodeType() {
    String returnval = this.nodeType;
    return returnval;
}

@Override
public String toString() {          
    return super.toString();
}

/**
 * This number is here for model snapshot storing purpose<br>
 * It needs to be changed when this class gets changed
 */ 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}



/**
* NodeLibrary
*/  
public class NodeLibrary implements java.io.Serializable {

private String libraryName;
public NodeObject [] nodeArray = new NodeObject[10];

/**
 * Default constructor
 */
public NodeLibrary(){
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

public void initiateNodes() {
    for(int i = 0; i < nodeArray.length; i++) {
        nodeArray[i].alternateConstruct("J16", true, true, true, "Junction");
    }
    return;
}

public String getLibraryName() {
    String returnval = this.libraryName;
    return returnval;
}

public String getNodeID2(int indexValue) {
    String returnval = nodeArray[indexValue].getNodeID();
    return returnval;
}

public boolean hasGate2(int indexValue) {
    boolean returnval = nodeArray[indexValue].hasGate();
    return returnval;
}

public boolean hasSecurityCamera2(int indexValue) {
    boolean returnval = nodeArray[indexValue].hasSecurityCamera();
    return returnval;
}

public boolean isExposed2(int indexValue) {
    boolean returnval = nodeArray[indexValue].exposed();
    return returnval;
}

public String getNodeType2(int indexValue) {
    String returnval = nodeArray[indexValue].getNodeType();
    return returnval;
}

@Override
public String toString() {          
    return super.toString();
}

/**
 * This number is here for model snapshot storing purpose<br>
 * It needs to be changed when this class gets changed
 */ 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

This code is executed in the Anylogic application

```
NodeLibrary Dtown = new NodeLibrary();
Dtown.initiateNodes();
```

This is the error message that I get

```
NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at epanet.NodeLibrary.initiateNodes(NodeLibrary.java:72)
    at epanet.WDS.enterState(WDS.java:765)
    at epanet.WDS.executeActionOf(WDS.java:675)
    at com.xj.anylogic.engine.Statechart.start(Unknown Source)
    at epanet.WDS.start(WDS.java:1886)
    at epanet.Main.start(Main.java:2484)
    at com.xj.anylogic.engine.Engine.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.xj.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.xj.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.run(Unknown Source)
    at epanet.Simulation.executeShapeControlAction(Simulation.java:85)
```

Comment: Please include the exact error message and tell us what line in the file the stack trace corresponds to.

Comment: Have you tried to add a breakpoint at line `NodeLibrary.java:72` and verify the values of variables used at that line?

Comment: Does this refer to Anylogic the modelling framework / application?  If so - you might want to add the agent-based-modelling and/or system-dynamics tags to give the best chance of attracting a specialist audience to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at epanet.NodeLibrary.initiateNodes(NodeLibrary.java:72)
```

tells you that you are accessing an Object that was not instatiated before. This happens at line 72 and is within the method `initiateNodes`.
From your code it can only be the line:

```
nodeArray[i].alternateConstruct("J16", true, true, true, "Junction");
```

At this line you are accessing the method `alternateConstruct` on an Object that you did not intialize before. You have to call the constructor before that. You could do:

```
nodeArray[i] = new NodeObject();
nodeArray[i].alternateConstruct("J16", true, true, true, "Junction");
```

Or you could (and this is the better solution) create a constructor that takes the same arguments as the method `alternatConstruct` and change the line to:

```
nodeArray[i] = new NodeObject("J16", true, true, true, "Junction");
```

Such a constructor would look like this:

```
public NodeObject(String ID, boolean gateInfo, boolean securityCameraInfo, boolean exposureInfo, String nodeTypeInfo){
    this.nodeID = ID;
    this.gate = gateInfo;
    this.securityCamera = securityCameraInfo;
    this.isExposed = exposureInfo;
    this.nodeType = nodeTypeInfo;
}
```

Comment: This solution worked absolutely wonderful for me. It also gave me some insight on how to properly instantiate objects. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this:
you're initializing `nodeArray` to an array, but that array is an array of references, which you don't seem to be initializing to instances of `NodeObject` anywhere. yet, in `initiateNodes()` you're dereferencing elements of the array, which are `null`.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand about java is when  you construct an array of custom defined objects, aka Nodeobject, you have to initialize them one by one.

```
public NodeObject [] nodeArray = new NodeObject[10];
```

This create an array of size 10, each is an reference pointer that should point to a NodeObject. But currently they are pointing to null.

A practical way is to initialize these instance variables in constructor

```
public NodeLibrary(){
    for(int i = 0; i < nodeArray.length; i++) {
        nodeArray[i]=new NodeObject();
    }
}
```

Then when you call them in initializeNodes function, they are not null.